# При открытии модального окна страницу перебрасывает наверх

Tags: окно

Добрый день!

Вот такая есть проблема, не могу сам разобраться, прошу помощи. Есть скрипт модального окна. Ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/LADYX/bvn7p1x7/

Проблема заключается в следующем. При открытии окна страницу перебрасывает вверх. Что я делаю не так, в чем моя ошибка?

Огромное спасибо за помощь, подсказку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда появляется модальное окно, scroll пропадает, так как у body устанавливается position: fixed. Соответственно страница уменьшается по высоте и браузер возвращает контент в нужные рамки. Поэтому и "подбрасывает".